# extract value from nested json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nested

Here is the [Jason url](http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/6374655)

and if you get a xml in your chrome put this inside of a IRB

```
@results = JSON.parse(open("http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/soklista/lan/", "Accept" => "application/json", "Accept-Language" => "sv").read)
```

Now I wonder how do I extract nested values from

```
["platsannons"]["arbetsplats"]["kontaktpersonlista"]["kontaktpersondata"]
```

I need to get the name ( ["namn"] ) so that it will display this

```
Carl Mårtensson
```

How do I do this. I have tried a .each do, but that only dispaly it like this

```
Carl Mårtensson [{"namn"=>"Carl Mårtensson", "telefonnummer"=>""}]
```

I know that I can use gsub, but that is not good practice :)

**EDIT**

Here is the documentation and on page 21 to page 23 you will see the Json structure that I am talking about. [Documentation](http://www.arbetsformedlingen.se/download/18.362b127c14924e08e87137a/1426768720944/tekniskbeskr_ledigajobb.pdf)

Thanks

Comment: http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/6374655
It is not JSON... it's XML

Comment: Okej, put this in a IRB and look for yourself then.

@results = JSON.parse(open("http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/soklista/lan/", "Accept" => "application/json", "Accept-Language" => "sv").read)

Answer (score 0):

First, that URL isn't JSON, but XML. As Arthur says you can use Nokogiri to get the data you want. Let's assume you've read that XML document into a string variable named `xml_string`.  You can then do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_string)
namn = doc.att('arbetsplats kontaktpersonlista kontaktpersondata namn').text
```

`namn` will now contain the value `Carl Mårtensson`

Comment: Yes, I know that I can parse it with nokogir, but the documentation by default is json and I want to use json. They have the exakt same nested tables. Any change you have a answer to the json problem that I have ?

Comment: @CyrusZei Without seeing the actual JSON, it's really hard to help.

Comment: here is a link to the documentation. [link](http://www.arbetsformedlingen.se/download/18.362b127c14924e08e87137a/1426768720944/tekniskbeskr_ledigajobb.pdf)]

look at the bottom of page 21 to page 23 and you will see the json structure

Comment: or use the IRB @results = JSON.parse(open("http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/soklista/lan/", "Accept" => "application/json", "Accept-Language" => "sv").read)

Comment: @CyrusZei if you can load the json into a variable, then just inspect it until you have the data you want. Not sure I understand where the issue is?